# Using camera with plyer on kivy: app reseting

Tags: android, python-2.7, kivy

I'm using plyer on a Kivy App (Android) and I'm able to use the camera, but after using it the App reset. Did I forget something?

`def chamar_camera(nome,pc,objeto,label_passa,instance): 

    agora = datetime.now()
    nome_arquivo = '%s_%s_%.4i_%.2i_%.2i_%.2i_%.2i_%.2i.jpg' % (nome,pc,agora.year,agora.month,agora.day,agora.hour,agora.minute,agora.second)
    def sair (): 
        if os.path.isfile(nome_arquivo) == True: label_passa.text = "Foto de "+pc+"tirada com sucesso"
    camera.take_picture(filename=nome_arquivo, on_complete=sair)`

When I had error on my code the App just closes, but it is not the case. 
I also took care for using on_pause and on_resume on my App class. 
Anybody with the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to the camera view pauses your app, so Kivy will close unless you have an `on_pause` method of your App class that returns True (see [this documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#pause-mode)):

```
def on_pause(self):
    return True
```

If you don't have this method, add it. If you do, it should work so post the full adb logcat log during the problem.

Comment: I had one, but inside class app, I put another one in this part:
<pre>
if __name__ in ('__main__','__android__'):
 
    DAP().run()
    
    def on_pause(self):return True
    def on_resume(self):pass
<code>

Comment: One important hint I learned now: unplug your usb cable to test Camera! It makes difference to me!

Comment: Now is reseting again. I guess is just a bug, doesn't make sense.